# Where to store preferences in a Java application?

Tags: java, jar, cross-platform, settings, preferences

I need just a solution to retrieve a path for storing desktop application settings (e.g. a sqlite database) that meets following needs:

- cross platform
- works from jar and from "normal" invocation

I've spent a lot of time googling and experimenting with getting the codebase path via `X.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` and `java.util.pref.Preferences`
class, but return values gave sometimes different results, returned null or just "/" as path.

"Cross Platform" is kind of hard to define. A solution called "best practice for each platform" won't be easy to achieve. Making a difference between user-specific and shared data would be sensible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`java.util.prefs.Preferences`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) is the proper way to do it. It works perfectly fine (I've used it in a desktop application without any problems). It is cross-platform and is available without any extra jars. It also differentiates between user-specific and global data. Perhaps shed some light on your particular problems with it (or ask another question)

Of course, you can use [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) as well, and store files in `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

Comment: To store app data under **~/.appdata** as suggested with `System.getProptery("user.dir")` would be a good approach to unix systems, but where is the cross platform aspect?

Comment: @phineas would return the user dir on all platforms. It will be `C:/documents and settings/<User>/` on windows.

Answer (score 0):

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns a path to the user directory for most modern systems.